# Can Neural Networks be used to maximize the output without knowing the expected output?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, game-theory

I'm currently doing research in Combinatorial Game Theory and I'm trying to develop an Artificial Intelligence using a Neural Network. My initial approach to this would be to take statistics of the game and use those as inputs, and train my Neural Network to develop the optimal weight configuration for those inputs in order to get a MAXIMAL output value for those inputs. Each set of inputs represents a move and by passing each move (input x weights) through the neural net I can find out which move has the maximal value. Thus, that move would be the best move to make.

This is all in theory and I'm just curious if constructing a neural net while not knowing the expected value is at all possible. If this doesn't seem reasonable are there any other algorithms I should look into for this sort of problem?

I appreciate any feedback, thank you in advance.

Comment: In the current form this makes not much sense as there is *no information at all* to the question: which move is better. Of course a NN can maximize the output for all moves, but that does not help at all without some assumptions. Imagine your moves look inputwise all the same except one (so that the NN might learn to distinguish them; that's unsupervised learning). Where is the information hidden that tells which move-group A or B should obtain the higher value? This is not possible without further assumptions.

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your comment. The moves won't be exactly identical as they will have different statistics representing them (i.e. - size of move, damage move makes, moves it leaves opponent). So would this still be considered unsupervised learning?

Comment: It's not about unsupervised or supervised learning. It's about giving your approach *some assumptions*. Without it's not possible in theory! Different statistics, very different, fine, it won't change anything. Of course the names ```damage move makes``` and ```moves it leaves opponent``` sound like they somehow correlate with some *value-function* (my assumption here: damage a move makes make it good -> increase NN-output value). But it's your job to make that connection / incorporate this kind of knowledge. Again... without it's unsolvable!

Comment: And if there is a winner at some time (you got some delayed value -1,0,1 at the end of some game), it's a basic Reinforcement-learning problem (one of the tougher ML-settings) where are many model-free algorithms available. Recently Q-learning was combined with NNs to great success.